# Get associated properties

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I need to fetch some data from associated tables, but I can't deal with it. I have the following tables with functions.

```php
Class User
{
    public function lastGoals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserGoals')->last()->with('data');
    }
}
```

```php
Class UserGoals
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'goal_id'
    ];

    public function data()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CreatorGoals', 'id', 'goal_id');
    }

    public function goalsBelong()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CreatorGoals', 'goal_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```php
Class CreatorGoals
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'label', 'type'
    ];

    public function scopeFront($query)
    {
        return $query->select('id', 'label', 'type')->where('is_front', 1);
    }
}
```

I need to fetch all UserGoals with UserID and it's labels,

For now I have:

```
$data = User::user(Auth::guard('web')->user()->id)->with('lastGoals')->first();
```

I have a collection of users but I don't know to fetch the label of each user goal. I have tried:

```
$data->lastGoals->data->label;
$data->lastGoals->label;
$data->data->lastGoals->label;
```

But I still have errors. How can I fetch the label of each user goal?

Comment: You probably have to loop `$data->lastGoals`, for example `foreach($data->lastGoals AS $lastGoal){ // $lastGoal->label;, etc }`. Sidenote, `Auth::guard('web')->user()` will return the `User`; you don't need to query for it again.

Comment: @timlewis Hi, thanks for advice with `Auth::guard('web')->user() `. `$lastGoal->label` in foreach loop returns me null :(

Comment: @timlews
Ok, but `$lastGoal->data->label` in foreach loop looks fine, thanks!

Comment: Nice, glad you go that working. Rule of thumb is that whenever something returns multiple objects in an array (or `Collection` in Laravel), don't try to access a property without a loop. Anyway, you're welcome to add a self-answer and accept that (when you can) to close this question.